# Selecting data frame columns by condition in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with several columns, with some of them corresponding to numeric variables, and some - to categorical.
How do I make a subset of this data.frame with only numeric or categorical variables?

Comment: Although R is a tool regularly used in statistics, this question concerns coding rather than the use of statistics itself - as such it's better suited to StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R w/o a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you could provide an example of the type of information you were looking to sort, however perhaps this is what you are looking for.

```
data <- data.frame(id=1:10, 
               type=sample(c("a,","b"), size=10,replace=TRUE),
               age=sample(5:20,size=10, replace= TRUE),
               colour=sample(c("red","blue","pink", "green"), size=10,replace=TRUE),
               qty=sample(100:150, size= 10, replace= TRUE))

data[,"factor"==sapply(data,class)]
data[,"integer"==sapply(data,class)]
```

If you want to always include the ID column you can do the following

```
data[,c(TRUE,"factor"==sapply(data[,-1],class))]
```

Comment: No problem, You can mark the question as answered if you want.